# Subquery with the same WHERE clause as query

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions, aggregate-filter

In Postgres 9.4, I have a table which contains user's emails sent by different senders. I need to generate the list of the recent distinct senders, I'm using following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (tableA.senderName) 
       tableA.senderName,tableA.received,tableA.someOtherColumn
FROM tableA 
WHERE tableA.received BETWEEN timeA AND timeB
ORDER BY tableA.senderName,tableA.received DESC
```

Since `tableA` contains all messages of all senders, this query gives me only the recent messages of the distinct senders and works quite well.

Actually, I have the whole query (except the `WHERE` clause, since `timeA` and `timeB` differ everytime) in a view and then I just `SELECT *` from this view using the particular `timeA` and `timeB` in the `WHERE` clause.

Now consider the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(ts_rank_cd(tableA.precompTSVector,constantTSQuery)) AS score 
FROM tableA 
WHERE tableA.precomTSVector @@ constantTSQuery
AND tableA.sender = someParticularSender
AND tableA.received BETWEEN timeA AND timeB
```

which gives the total score of searching some constant TS query against all messages of a particular sender within the given time range.

I would like to incorporate this query (perhaps as a subquery) into my view so that I can also see the "score" for each distinct sender. The obvious problem is that the "score query" is dependent on the actual `timeA` and `timeB` in the WHERE clause. These times are not known until the view itself is queried.

**EDIT:** A different problem is the `someOtherColumn` being also selected in the first query (and potentially some other columns which I would also like to incorporate in the view) - since the an aggregate function is being used.

Any ideas how to achieve this? Or perhaps some different approach is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (senderName) 
       senderName, received -- add more columns as you please
     , SUM(ts_rank_cd(precompTSVector,constantTSQuery)) 
         FILTER (WHERE precomTSVector @@ constantTSQuery)
         OVER (PARTITION BY senderName) AS score 
FROM   tableA
WHERE  received BETWEEN timeA AND timeB
ORDER  BY senderName, received DESC;
```

First you need to get `DISTINCT ON` right:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

`DISTINCT ON` is applied *after* aggregate functions, that's why you can combine both in a single `SELECT`. Consider the sequence of events in a `SELECT` query:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied-in-php-postgresql/8242764#8242764)

About the new aggregate `FILTER` clause (requires Postgres **9.4**):

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

You need to run this as [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS), if you want to add more (unaggregated) columns.

If `received` can be NULL, you'll want to use `DESC NULLS LAST`:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Depending on data distribution and cardinalities, other query techniques may or may not be faster:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Comment: Thanks - Im using 9.4. Gotta try this out!

Comment: Okay, this works well! But there's another problem which I now need to overcome - since there's now the aggregate function being used, I cannot select any more columns than those specified in the ORDER BY or GROUP BY clause, am I correct? I got the infamous `column "someOtherColumn" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: @Right, we need to run this as window function then. I added some more. You do want the sum *per sender*, right?

Comment: Wow, I am speechless! Thanks a lot!

Comment: After some further investigation, I think it is worth noting the fact that because of using the *window function* Postgres will not "push down" the `WHERE`-clause when querying the view. This will most likely have some performance implications. C.f: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533877/will-postgres-push-down-a-where-clause-into-a-view-with-a-window-function-aggre

Comment: @NumberFour: Like I suggested under the linked question: a function taking `timeA` and `timeB` as parameters (instead of a view) could fix that.